# how to read "%" character from char array and write it to a file using fprintf_s?

Tags: c++, special-characters

I have a piece of code where I need to read "%" character from a char array and write it to a file using fprintf_s;

```
FILE *fp = <some valid file ptr>;
char sBuf = " %Demo";
fprintf_s(fp, szBuf);
```

The problem here is , fprintf_s asserts while reading % (most likely because it doesn't find a valid format specifier). 
Is there a way to write the "%" character to the file ? If not by tweaking the above code, it would be great to hear other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never, ever use a computed string as a format parameter to the `scanf`/`printf` family of functions.

Either use:

```
fprintf_s(fp, "%s", szBuf);
```

... or directly use `fwrite`, as you don't actually format anything here.

Comment: Thanks a ton! That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format that is already supported by the `printf` family of functionis -- use `%%` to print a `%`.

```
char const* sBuf = " %%Demo";
```

The other but less straightforward method would be to use `%c` to print a `%`.

```
char const* sBuf = " %cDemo";
fprintf_s(fp, sBuf, '%');
```